# DetailsView and Parent-Child tables - inserting rows

Tags: c#, .net, database, binding

When you have parent-child tables and you wish to use a DetailsView to edit the data how do you do it using a SqlDataSource?

For example, if you have a Person and an Employee table (where an employee is the child table and the Person is parent table - an employee derives from a person).
Person
 P_ID
 FirstName
 LastName
 DOB
Employee
 E_ID
 P_ID
 EmployeedID
 Title
 HireDate

- The SQL statement returns all the information for the employee (First and Last Name, DOB, EmployeeID, Title, HireDate).
- User should be able to edit and insert an employee using a single DetailsView, instead of 2 DetailsView (one for Person and the other for employee)
- When inserting, the record for person should be created first and then the ID assigned to employee)

So how does one go about doing this?
 1. Using a SQLDataSource
 2. Using a DataSet

Comment: This seems like a 'plz send teh codez' answer.  How about showing us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx ?

Comment: Nope - doesnt show you how to insert a record such that the data goes into 2 tables. (more over, where one table has to get updated before the other: Person needs to be created before Employee).